# How to simulate a continuous key press

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, events, core-graphics

I need to simulate a continuous key press. For example hold down the 'c' key for 5 seconds. To simulate a key press event I tried to use CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent:

```
let event:CGEventRef! = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(nil, 8, true)
CGEventPost(CGEventTapLocation.CGSessionEventTap, event)
```

But it acts like if the button is tapped and then released immediately. I need to create an event that keeps holding the button (key down) and then release it (key up).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here.  Do you mean that the reaction of the button should be delayed by 5 seconds and only trigger if the uses presses the button again within 5 seconds ?   Does the visual also need to reflect this somehow ?  Or perhaps you need to travel in time 5 seconds back and make the button stay pressed for the past X seconds if the user presses it again within 5 seconds in the future. (where is Doc Brown when you need him?)

Comment: I mean that when the user presses a specific key, the system should simulate a continuous pressing. For example I press 'A' and immediately release it, but the system acts as if I'm holding the 'A' key until I press it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but it appears that the system will continue to hold the button down. This simple experiment shows it.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    print("waiting 4 seconds, use this time to position your cursor in a text field")
    let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(4 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.insertLetterZ()
    })
}

func insertLetterZ() {
    print("pressing shift")
    self.tapButton(56)

    print("holding button for 2 seconds")
    let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        print("tapping z, but Z will be selected (since shift is still being pressed)")
        self.tapButton(6)

        print("untapping z and shift")
        self.untapButton(6)
        self.untapButton(56)
    })
}

func tapButton(button: CGKeyCode) {
    let event = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(nil, button, true)
    CGEventPost(CGEventTapLocation.CGSessionEventTap, event)
}

func untapButton(button: CGKeyCode) {
    let event = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(nil, button, false)
    CGEventPost(CGEventTapLocation.CGSessionEventTap, event)
}
```

This code however does **not** capitalize a letter if a user taps the keyboard when shift is programmatically pressed. I have also noticed that if the cursor location is changed between shift and z being tapped "z" will be inserted instead of "Z"